# VB .net - stored procedure - line number count

Tags: vb.net

I'm back again as I'm waiting for the coffee to kick in and have another question that seems to be not causing my brain cells to fire correctly.

I've set the following code to determine the line numbers of all rows returned from the procedure loop.

```
linenum = 0
Do While (rsData.Read())
  linenum = linenum + 1
loop
```

Now I'm trying to code a button that will move users to different sections depending on the linenumber returned.

So if there's only one linenum with a value of 1, they get a button to 'Apply'.

If the total linenum values are greater than 1, they get a button to 'select apply date'.

Now again I'm having a brain fart and can't think of the logic if theres a linenum of 1+ how to determine the button should be displayed. It needs to include the value of 1 as well as there are more than one linenums so the button should display the 'select apply button'.

Any ideas?

Thanks!

Comment: Does each record have its own button?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you'll have better luck populating a `DataTable` and using the row indexes, or returning the row number from the stored procedure.

```
SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY SalesYTD DESC) AS Row, FirstName, LastName, ROUND(SalesYTD,2,1) AS YTD 
FROM Sales.vSalesPerson
WHERE TerritoryName IS NOT NULL AND SalesYTD <> 0
```

It looks like you're using a `SqlDataReader` currently, so it shouldn't be too difficult to adjust so it returns a `DataTable` instead:

```
DataTable table = new DataTable();

using (SqlDataAdapter adap = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd))
{
    adap.Fill(table);        
}
```

Comment: I was trying to avoid doing it in the SP but on reflection it does look as if that would  be the best option.

Answer (score 0):

Not clear what you're trying to accomplish, but to directly answer your question:

```
if linenum = 0 then
  mybutton.visible = false
else if linenum = 1 then
  mybutton.visible = true
  mybutton.text = "Apply"
else
  mybutton.visible=true
  mybutton.text = "Apply select"
end if
```

But I would think that if linenum > 1, someplace you also have to giv the user the list of things to select from, and a way to select one of them. Like build a dropdown box or something.